# Getting Undefined method 'deprecate' error in Ruby dbi Gem

Tags: ruby, dbi

I have installed ruby dbi-0.4.3 and I'm attempting to connect to a SQL Server DB.  The gem installed without problems.  The deprecate method is being used in the Date.rb file that's part of the gem.  Thanks in advance for any help.
Chris

Here is my code:

```
require 'dbi'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__File__))

oConn = DBI.connect('DBI:ADO:Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source="UPSTAIRS\SQLEXPRESS";
                      Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SQLClass')

oConn.disconnect if dbh
```

Here is the Error I am getting:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.3/lib/dbi/utils/date.rb:57:in `<class:Date>': undefined method `deprecate' for DBI::Date:Class (NoMethodError)
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.3/lib/dbi/utils/date.rb:7:in `<module:DBI>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.3/lib/dbi/utils/date.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.3/lib/dbi/utils.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.3/lib/dbi.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from C:/SQLClassScripts/RubyScripts/LoadData/lib/LoadDataMain.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You can indent code and output with 4 spaces - it's easier to read. (I edited your code)

Comment: As other have pointed out, the dbi library isn't particularly well maintained.  There are a number of pending pull requests in the github repository.  If you are set on using dbi, you might investigate if one of these pull requests would solve your problem, and simply build your own version of the gem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `dbi`, but the `deprecate`-method seems to be from [deprecated-gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/deprecated).

Does a

```
gem 'deprecated' 
require 'deprecated'
```

at the begin of the code help?

Comment: Ok, it was a try ;) As others also said: dbi is outdated. I recommend also to use sequel.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the ruby-dbi library is outdated.  The last time the library was touched was over 3 years ago.  You might be better off using a gem that provides similar functionality with dependencies defined properly.  One option is [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel)

Comment: I'm going to try this-  I will report back-  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As knut wrote "dbi" require "deprecated" gem, but specific version - 2.0.1. You can see this at page https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/blob/master/lib/dbi.rb :38

```
begin
    require "rubygems"
    gem "deprecated", "= 2.0.1"
rescue LoadError
end
```